# Stop script while a file is not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code and I'd like to stop the script while $.get() is not finished.

```
$.get("assets/data/html/navigation.html", function(response) {
    $('body').append(response);
});
$('body').append('<div class="modal">...</div>');
```

In this example the second append is executed before the first one.

Thanx for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't want to stop the script, you want to go on **from** inside the callback :

```
$.get("assets/data/html/navigation.html", function(response) {
    $('body').append(response);
    doOtherStuff();
});
function doOtherStuff(){
    $('body').append('<div class="modal">...</div>');
}
```

Or, using `done` :

```
$.get("assets/data/html/navigation.html", function(response) {
    $('body').append(response);
}).done(function(){
    $('body').append('<div class="modal">...</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to jQuery documentation:

```
    var jqxhr = $.get("assets/data/html/navigation.html", function(response) {
      $('body').append(response);
    })
    .done(function() {
      $('body').append('<div class="modal">...</div>');
    })
```